# Store Git tags as version in database?

Tags: mysql, git, git-tag

Suppose I have tag a commit as v0.1.0 and I want to store v0.1.0 in the version field in the database. Is there any way to fetch tag value directly in the database or I have to manually enter the tag value in the database?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What database are we talking about? How does it connect with your git?

Comment: I am asking for a SQL query to insert the git-tag value v0.1.0 in version row of my database.Do I need to connect database to git so that whenever I create a tag release,the version field automatically changes or I can simply insert the git-tag value in my database manually everytime I create a new tag?